# Cannot find resource named 'CloseButton'. Resource names are case sensitive

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use [Growl Alike WPF Notification](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499241/Growl-Alike-WPF-Notifications) in another WCF application. But I'm getting an error when trying to run it. The ***error*** that I'm getting is :

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.

When I check the inner exception, it says

> Cannot find resource named 'CloseButton'. Resource names are case sensitive.

But when I check the ButtonStyle.xaml it has the resource `CloseButton`.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="Black" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" Color="Black" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />



<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CloseNormal" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#394452" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#343e4a" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CloseOver" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#515a6b" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#474f5d" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ClosePressed" Color="#090909" />

<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle 
        Margin="2"
        StrokeThickness="1"
        Stroke="#60000000"
        StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CloseButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="0" ClipToBounds="False" Background="{StaticResource CloseNormal}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Opacity=".4" BlurRadius="5" Color="Black"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/close.png" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="2">
                                <Image.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Direction="90" ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="1"/>
                                </Image.Effect>
                            </Image>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CloseOver}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ClosePressed}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Does any one have a clue what is it that I'm missing??

***NOTE ::*** Source code works fine when run as a individual project

Answer (score 11):

In order to use `StaticResource`, the style has to be defined before the element you are trying to apply it to within the same visual tree.

You could add your resource dictionary to a control's resources above the button in the visual tree

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyle.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}">Click</Button>
</Grid>
```

or instead you could use `DynamicResource`, which does not require the style to be at the same level or above in the visual tree.

```
<Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Style="{DynamicResource CloseButton}">Click</Button>
```

Comment: In case it helps the next person, I directly copied my xaml from a ".net 6.0" project to a ".net-framework 4.7.2" project and suddenly I was getting "exception: cannot find resource named 'RoundButton'",  etc..  I changed my xaml from <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundedButton}"...> to <Button Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButton}"....> and presto the exception was gone and my formatting was working again.  This worked for buttons, fonts, etc..

Answer (score 2):

XAML is cached.  VS locks it when you have the *.xaml and *xaml.cs files open.  Close them in Visual Studio and you may see the problem go away.

Answer (score 1):

example

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/UI/ButtonStyle.xaml" ></ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

maybe this could be.use Pack URIs load files

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf